# c# Unit Testing for Generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have to test the below generic method which is internal class of another assembly.

```
internal class JsonSerializationUtility
{ 
  public static string SerializeJson<T>(T obj) 
  { 
    string jsonFormattedString = string.Empty; 
    try { 
        MemoryStream memStreamObj = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerObj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)); 
        jsonSerObj.WriteObject(memStreamObj, obj); 
        memStreamObj.Position = 0; StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memStreamObj); 
        jsonFormattedString = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        Log.Error("Exception details: ", ex); 
    } 
  return jsonFormattedString; 
  }
}
```

and i have tried in this way:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SerializeJson() 
{ 
    PrivateType privateObj = new PrivateType(typeof(JsonSerializationUtility)); 
    string input= "WorldCup2015"; 
    string output = privateObj.InvokeStatic("SerializeJson<objectType>", input).ToString(); 
    Assert.IsNotNull(output); 
}
```

But i am getting the missing method reference. Can anyone suggest how should have to test for Generic method.

I had done same procedure of writing test code for simple static method, but unable for generic method.

Comment: You typically don't test internal code directly - you test whatever _calls_ that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload.

Use [`PrivateType.InvokeStatic Method (String, Type[], Object[], Type[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546306.aspx) to invoke a generic method.

Note that I, too, would use `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestProject")]`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried as suggested, but I am getting exception, could you please help me where am I going wrong, The below is the exception I am getting.
              string input= "WorldCup2015";
              PrivateType privateObj = new PrivateType(typeof(JsonSerializationUtility));
              Type[] types = new Type[1];
              types[0] = typeof(string);
              Object[] argumentObjarray = new Object[1];
              argumentObjarray[0] = input;
              privateObj.InvokeStatic("SerializeJson", types, argumentObjarray, types);
           }

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution for testing `internal` classes is to use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).